# Flutter: Live ml kit text recognition with camera plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-mlkit

How to recognize text with the ml kit plugin from live bytes from the camera plugin?

Comment: did u solve the issue ?

Comment: did you solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [firebase ml vision sample app](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_ml_vision/example/lib/camera_preview_scanner.dart) ?

Comment: to use  firebase ml vision you need a setup a firebase account, which some developers or clients would like to avoid. Whereas, the ML kit is a standalone sdk kit. So people prefer this!